# Embed user control on web page

Tags: c#, html, object, activex, embed

I am using c# to create user control , i build the myControll.dll.

But how can i embed this on a web page ? I am not using `Asp.net`.

I tried the following

```
<OBJECT id="myControll" name="myControll.dll#myControll.userControl" >
</OBJECT>
```

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Either you're using the terminology incorrectly, or you're not understanding how controls in ASP.NET work.  If you have an ASP.NET user control, you can't use it without using ASP.NET.  HTML alone won't interpret it.  The client-side browser won't be able to make sense of the server-side .NET code.

Comment: @David its not asp.net user control.

Comment: Your question seems to indicate otherwise.  Can you update the question to explain what this object is and how you expect to use it?

Comment: @David i am not a c# guy ,but learning to do , i just created a class library project and added a user control on it.and attached a simple button.and built the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I know that framework 1.1 and 2.0 have config tools. Set full code trust for Url (127.0.0.7 - local for example). (3.0-3.5 use 2.0 tool)
2. Add site (for example 127.0.0.1) to trusted sites zone in IE. May be you need enable other radio box in advanced.
3. framework 4-4.5 have not config tools. I suppose that .manifest file or certificates or (SRP) Control Panel -> Administration -> Local Security Policy -> software restriction policy or AppLocker have not effect. I tried this but unsuccessful.
   Some people recommend COM attribute or check 2 boxes in project setting. I am not understand why (I test it of despair).

caspol may be help.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(v=vs.100).aspx

Sorry for my English!